# Can PowerPoint templates support multiple languages?

Tags: templates, powerpoint, multilingual

I need to make a PowerPoint template with a set of about 10 master slide layouts.  Several of these include text like "About our firm..." and "Before you begin..."

Is there a way to have the slide layouts support multiple languages so our German offices get the same layouts with "Über unsure Firma..." and "Bevor Sie beginnen?"

Ideally, I would only have one PPT template to support.  We are using Microsoft Office 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to have multiple templates to make this fly, or write add-in code to set the language for the presentation at user request.  You'd probably need to do this in any case, because even if the text changes, if the language for the text is marked as, say, English, your German text will be flagged as misspelled, and if the presentation is set to English, any German text the user enters will get the red-squigglies as well.